# Homology functors and weak cofibers

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, homotopy-theory

I'm looking at a remark in the paper

Kainen, Paul C., "Weak Adjoint Functors", *Mathematische Zeitschrift* 122 (1971).

It is supposed to prove that generalized homology functors fail to preserve weak cofibers. Here is a picture of the remark.

[image]

Here, a weak colimit has the existence property of an ordinary colimit but may not satisfy the uniqueness property. And a homology functor for Kainen is a functor $\mathsf{Ho}(\mathbf{CW}_{\ast}^c) \to \mathbf{Ab}$ from the homotopy category of pointed connected CW complexes that takes cofiber sequences in $\mathbf{CW}_{\ast}^c$ to exact sequences in $\mathbf{Ab}$ and preserves small coproducts.

I'm confused as to why Kainen never addresses the scenario where the inclusion $i : C \to h(B)$ does split. Can we always find a cofiber sequence $A \to X \to B$ such that $i$ doesn't split?

Comment: There are homology theories for which every such $i: C \rightarrow h(B)$ splits. For example, singular homology with coefficients in a field. I find it likely that the author really meant to demonstrate that many homology theories do not preserve weak colimits.

Comment: @ConnorMalin I see, thanks. What are some homology theories where we can find such an $i$ that doesn't split? I can't think of an obvious example.

Comment: There should be plenty of examples for singular homology with integer coefficients. Just try to find a cofiber sequence $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ such that $\mathbb{Z} \cong H_i(Y) \rightarrow H_i(Z) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ is multiplication by 2.